# Accessing Pre Populated DB in Phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I have created a new database externally and placed that in the assets folder as given here. http://gauravstomar.blogspot.in/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html. I have used the code in my activity and the database is successfully copied in the respective folder. Now I am not able to figure out how to access the data from this database. The `window.openDatabase(database_name, database_version, database_displayname, database_size);` function creates a new database and replace it with the existing one.

I want to know is their any way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use the sqlite plugin to access and modify the database.

[Plugin Link](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin)

The installation guide is well written and if followed correctly, the plugin take minutes to get installed
[Guide](https://github.com/lite4cordova/Cordova-SQLitePlugin#installing)

Not sure about the converter from SQL to SQLite